# How to assign 2-d arrays' to one another?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

**Components**

I have a string, for example

`char block[4][256] = "";`

and I have sentence

`char sentence[256] = "Bob walked his dog";`

I also have an iterator variable

`int pos = 0;`

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am trying to assign each word in the array `sentence` into the 2-d block array `block` in sequence.

For instance,

Let's say I have this code (my own write-up - didn't work as I had planned)

```
for (int x=0; x < ((int)strlen(sentence)); x++)
{
    if (sentence[x] == ' ') // not using strcmp at the moment to be more clear
    {
        ++pos; // move to the next word after space
        for (int y=0; y < pos; y++) // scan through the word
        {
            for (int z=0; z < x; z++) // add the word to the array
            {
                block[y][z] = sentence[z]; // assign the block (!!confusion here!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How I see it**

The way I see it by approaching this problem I need to first scan the sentence until I encounter a space ' ' character, a blank. After encountering this I have to re-scan the sentence and start adding all the characters up to the position of that blank space ' ' into the first segment of my block array `block[y][z]`, z being the iterator in the for statement above, and y being the position + 1 for every space encountered. I believe my main problem here is understanding how to assign 2-d arrays. If anyone see's a better approach to this problem I would love to hear it, thanks!

**The output I want**

After printing the contents of `block[x][256]` I want every x to output each word in the array that I am scanning for example. If I have something like this.

```
for (int a=0; a < 4; a++)
{
    for (int b=0; b < strlen(block[a][]); b++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", block[a][b]);
    }
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
block[0][]: Bob 
block[1][]: walked 
block[2][]: his
block[3][]: dog
```

Can anyone help of how I can approach this problem? Thanks!

Comment: In that regard - I am sorry, I removed that piece of code as it was  in account of an earlier part of my project.

Comment: If it is C++, why aren't you using `std::string`, `std::vector<std::string>`, as well as `cout`, etc.?  Also, `std::istringstream` could be used to separate the input into words.  In other words, your problem could be reduced to just a few lines of `C++` code.

Comment: @user3251225 Also, what if the input contained 5 words?  10 words?  100 words?  How are you going to adjust that array to hold the number of words above 4?  It would be hard to believe that your requirements are always going to be 4 words.

Comment: C or C++? In  C++ `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` are easily assignable!

Comment: I was actually going for a simple 'C' solution. Such as the one provided by Oregon. C++ is acceptable in terms of function calls, but I don't like the gesture of it. This std::vector<std::vector<int>> as recommended by Paul and Basile confused me even more since I don't understand the background of those calls. None-the-less thank-you both very much for your effort but I will be going with Oregon's answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you were going for.

```
int word_start = 0, word_end = 0, current_word = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < strlen(sentence) + 1; x++)
{
    if (sentence[x] == ' ' || sentence[x] == '\0')
    {
        word_end = x;
        int y, z;
        for (y = 0, z = word_start; z < word_end; y++, z++)
        {
            block[current_word][y] = sentence[z];
        }
        word_start = x + 1;
        current_word++;
    }
}
```

Here's the program that I used to test it, if it's not working for you and you'd like to see how I interpreted your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (const int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    char block[4][256] = {0};
    char sentence[256] = "Bob walked his dog";

    int word_start = 0, word_end = 0, current_word = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(sentence) + 1; x++)
    {
        if (sentence[x] == ' ' || sentence[x] == '\0')
        {
            word_end = x;
            int y, z;
            for (y = 0, z = word_start; z < word_end; y++, z++)
            {
                block[current_word][y] = sentence[z];
            }
            word_start = x + 1;
            current_word++;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", block[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `memcpy` instead of the loop?

Comment: I'd say `memcpy` is an optimization the OP can utilize once he understands the principles involved.

Comment: I would show the proper solution with dynamic allocation of the output buffer and `strlcpy`, but this is more to the point and in the style of the question.

Comment: Updated my answer. There were two bugs. One was not checking for `\0` in order to grab the last word in the sentence. The other was not using a separate iterator, `y` to store to each word into `block[x]` starting at index 0.

Answer (score 4):

While storing into block,

```
for (int i=0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    for (int j=0 ; j < 256 ; j++) 
    {
        if (sentence[j] == ' ') 
        {
            block[i][j] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        block[i][j]=sentence[j];
    }
}
```

While printing,

```
for (int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
{
    printf ("block[%d][]: %s\n", i, block[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate the time you put into writing this though I was looking for a more universal answer such as Oregons. Which by edits it won't restrict me a 4 word sentence. +1 for your efforts. Thank-you!

Answer (score 3):

First, just as a note -- your problem will be much greater if you ever need to store anything above 4 words, and especially if you're writing things in `C` instead of using `C++` and the various containers that are available in C++.

Since the answers (so far) have 'C' solutions, here is a C++ solution using `std::istringstream` and `std::string`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    char block[4][256] = { 0 };
    char sentence[] = "Bob walked his dog";

    std::istringstream sstrm(sentence);
    int curWord = 0;
    std::string s;
    while (sstrm >> s)
    {
        memcpy(&block[curWord][0], s.c_str(), s.size());
        ++curWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: More C++-like would be to replace `memcpy` with `std::copy( s.begin(), s.end(), &block[curWord][0] );`

Comment: Of course, if this is used in "real code" then you should check that `curWord < 4`, and that `s.size() < 256` or equivalent

Comment: Although I was looking for a more 'C' oriented solution, I do appreciate the unique C++ perspective on it. I'm sure it might help someone looking for an answer similar to this in the future. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

Following block works .. you will need to take care of multiple spaces if there are in the sentence.

```
unsigned int x = 0;
size_t length =  strlen(sentence);
unsigned int word=0 ;
while (x < length)
{
        // copy this word to block
        unsigned charactercount = 0;
        char character = sentence[x++] ;
        while (x<=length && ' ' != character )
        {
            block[word][charactercount++] = character;
            character = sentence[x++] ;
        }
        if (' ' == character || 0 == character)
        {
            block[word][charactercount++] = 0;
            word++;
        }
}
```